# catkin_make turotial error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was going through the ROS tutorials. After making the catkin workspace:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
```

I try to run catkin_make as explained in tutorial:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
```

How ever I got an error msg :

ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.topological_order import topological_order" failed: No module named cmake
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.

python-catkin-pkg is installed and up-to-date. Also when I run $PYTHONPATH I get:
bash: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages: Is a directory

I removed and reinstall ROS but didnt have any effect. I use ROS groovy and ubuntu 12.04.

How I fix this?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67669/catkin_make-turotial-error/) by [Manolis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5455/manolis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-07-18**:
Did you install ROS using `apt-get`?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-18**:
Which tutorial are you doing? What ones have you already done?

**Comment by [Manolis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5455/manolis/) on 2013-07-18**:
I have done the old beginner tutorials and now I am going through new beginner tutorials with catkin. Yes I have installed ROS using apt-get

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-07-18**:
Is this the tutorial you are doing? http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu. Have you initialized rosdep and source setup.bash?

**Comment by [Manolis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5455/manolis/) on 2013-07-19**:
Gustav, yes , I started from the installation and then gone to tutorials. I have initialized rosdep and sourced the setup.bash. Also I run rosdep update. but I get this:  ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml]:

**Comment by [Manolis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5455/manolis/) on 2013-07-19**:
Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I couldn’t find any other solution I just removed Linux partition and reinstalled everything (Ubuntu 12.04, ROS etc).
Now it works.

---

Originally posted by [Manolis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5455/manolis/) with karma: 16 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0